# Webpage is infinitely loading when I use insertBefore() method

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to modify the body section based on the `tagName`, using JavaScript. But my webpage is loading infinitely when I use `insertBefore()` method to insert a tag before the `<h1>` tag. This problem is not happening when I try to insert before some other elements. I am new to JS, please help me.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Para 1</p>
    <p>Para 2</p>
    <h1 id="head1">Para 3</h1>
    <p id="parax"></p>
    <div id="div1">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <ul id="mylist1">
        <li>Script</li>
        <li>deep learning</li>
        <li>software testing</li>
        <li>Python programming</li>
        <li>Database systems</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="firstp">I was supposed to be first.</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunc()">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cn=document.body.children;
    for(var i=0;i<cn.length;i++){
        if(cn[i].tagName=="DIV"){
            var h1 = document.createElement("H1");                 
            var text = document.createTextNode("h1 tag inserted");         
            h1.appendChild(text);                              
            cn[i].appendChild(h1);
        }
        else if(cn[i].tagName=="UL"){
            var lis= cn[i].childNodes;
            for(var j=0;j<lis.length;j++){
                if(lis[j].innerHTML=="Python programming")
                    lis[j].innerHTML="machine learning";
            }
         }
        
        else if(cn[i].tagName=="H1"){
            var p=document.createElement("P");
            var text=document.createTextNode("New para inserted before");
            p.appendChild(text);
            document.body.insertBefore(p,cn[i]);
        }
        else
            document.write();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

At this line i am facing problem (I think so) :

```
document.body.insertBefore(p,cn[i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you with this line code:

```
document.body.insertBefore(p,cn[i]);
```

increase number of `document.body.children` and every time you insert child you and number of body children and you never not hit last index.

please add this to see:

```
  document.body.insertBefore(p,cn[i]);
  alert(document.body.children.length); // add this line after insertBefore
```

see every alert show the number of `document.body.children` was increase

Comment: Thank you! I understood the mistake now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr @foad , I got the answer for my question. Actually the `insertBefore()` method is inside a `for` loop. So in every iteration, a new tag is added to the body and the `length` of the body increases by 1. This caused the infinite loading.

The correction is to add a break statement after the `insertBefore` method:

```
document.body.insertBefore(p,cn[i]);
 break;
```

This terminates the loop after adding the `<p>` tag before `<h1>` tag.